# unable to mock import that is being used inside a System Under Test class definition

Tags: python, mocking

I am new to Python programming language in general, as well as Python's **unittest** and **unittest.mock** system library packages. I am trying to write an unit test to test out an instance method **(System under Test)** for a Python custom class that I wrote. The module where this class resides, has a bunch of imports. I am trying to mock these imports but I am unable to do so. I have been reading lots of sample test examples as well as read python docs for **unittest.mock** library, but still unable to get it to work. I would sincerely appreciate any pointers, to get me going.

Here is the concise code summary of what I am trying to do.

The Package Structure:

- loader

  - extract

    - extract_data.py
  - utils

    - dbpool.py
- test

  - test_extract.py

Here is the code that matters.

extract_data.py

```
from ..utils import dbpool as dbpool
class ExtractService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = dbpool.get_connection()

    def nvl(self, value):
        if value and value.strip():
            return value.strip()
        else:
            return 'null'
```

dbpool.py

```
def get_connection():
    pool = SimpleConnectionPool() # left out the full defn for simplicity
    return pool.getconn()
```

test_extract.py

```
from loader.extract.extract_data import ExtractService
class TestExtractService:
    def test_extract(self):
        service = ExtractService() # test fails here as it is trying to initialize the object by invoking __init__ method which inturn looks for a reference to dbpool module
        assert service.nvl('  ') == 'null'
        assert service.nvl('    SO Rocks    ') == 'SO Rocks'
```

When I run the test, the test will try to get a **real connection** which I definitely do not want. So, I am trying to mock the **import dbpool** on the extract_data.py, and wanted to patch my own **get_connection** function.

I spent so many hours trying to get this to work using multiple combinations of @patch and @patch.object decorators but nothing seems to work. I am actually lost on how to do this. I am not even sure, if I am going down the right path and unfortunately, I do not know any python experts personally to check where I am going wrong. I would really appreciate if the experts here can point me to the right direction.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not familiar with @patch, but you could simply do `dbpool.get_connection = your_mock`